# How to pass variable to isset function in php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to return a `$user_id` variable from file to `if(isset(...))` statement. I will perform a different if statement but just trying to `echo` out the `$user_id` variable to test that I am setting the page.

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
include 'init.image.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/overall_header.php';

if(isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false){
$username       = $_GET['username'];


if(user_exists($username) === true){
$user_id        = user_id_from_username($username);
$profile_data   = user_data($user_id, 'first_name','last_name','email', 'username');
?>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?>'s Yor Page</h1>

<div id="navWrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="uploads/profile/blank_profile.gif" width="150" height="150" id="blank_profile"></a>
        </li>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=albums">Albums</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=music">Music</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='albums'){

$albums = get_profile_albums($user_id);

if(empty($albums)){
echo 'No Albums';
}else{

foreach($albums as $album){
if (empty($album['image'])) {
    $album['image'] = 'uploads/profile/blank_profile.gif';
}
?>
 <p><?php echo $album['name'],' (', $album['count'], ')'?> <br />
  <a href="<?php echo $profile_data['username'];?>?action=album_id=<?php echo $album['id'];?>">
    <img src="uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $album['id'];?>/<?php echo $album['image'];?>" />
  </a><br />
  <?php echo $album['description'];?>...<br />
</p>
<?php
}
}

}
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album_id=$album['id']'){
echo $user_id;
}



if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='music'){
echo'<h1>Music</h1>';
}

}else{
    echo 'Sorry, that user doesn\'t exist';
}
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include 'includes/overall/overall_footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: There's no need to add `=== boolean`.

Comment: You're doing it right... what is the problem/error you are getting?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking? I did notice this though: `isset($_GET['username']) === true` - as `isset` returns a boolean you don't need to use a `===` and if you want to shorten your statement, you could write it as `if(isset($_GET['username']))` which will only evaluate if returns a true anyhow.

Comment: There is no need to call both `isset()` and `empty()` on the same variable. `empty()` implicitly calls `isset()` so simply `!empty()` will suffice.

Comment: Ok i removed the true and still same results which is no results echoed, but if I move that variable outside the if statement and echo it, it displays the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes do not parse the string but double quotes do. For example:

```
$album_id = 1;
echo 'album_id=$album_id ';
echo "album_id=$album_id";
```

Will result in `album_id=$album_id album_id=1`

Thus, `$_GET['action']=='album_id=$album_id'` is checking if `$_GET['action']` is equal to `'album_id=$album_id'` and not what `$album_id` is evaluated to.

Your check should be more along these lines:

```
if (/* ... */ && $_GET['action']=="album_id=$album_id") {
```

**Edit**: Suggestion.

You should check `$_GET['action']` **once** and store `$action`. From there create an `if/else if/else` statement checking each possible type of action (music, albums, **album**, etc). If a type of action requires extra user supplied data, include that in the respective if block. For example:

```
 $action = $_GET['action'];
 // URL: /script.php?action=albums
 if ($action == 'albums') {
     // ...
 }
 // URL: /script.php?action=album&album_id=12
 else if ($action == 'album') {
     if (!empty($_GET['album_id'])) {
          $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
          echo "User with id $user_id is trying to access album with id $album_id";
     }
     // ...
 }
 // ...
```

No more `$_GET['action']=="album_id=$album_id"`

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I need to get the action of the link being clicked,  if you look up further in my code where the link this isset is referring to is I am passing a function in the link so how do I check with $_GET action to return that link dynamicly>

Comment: I made an edit with a suggestion. Instead of having `action=album_id=121` you check if action is album and then you get the album_id. I hope that is what you were getting at.

Comment: No that is not working I edited my original code the variable is $album['id'] not $album_id.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the variable correctly.

What I'm more concerned with in the following line is:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album_id=$album_id'){
```

`'album_id=$album_id'` doesnt look right and is probably why your if is not firing... It looks like you're trying to use the variable `$album_id` wrapped in single quotes and that will not substitute the value and rather keep `$album_id` in tact. I'm not sure if this is what you intended but if not its likely the source of your problem.

Comment: ok I thought maybe as well, how do I pass that variable $album_id then?

Comment: I mean how do I concat $album_id?

Comment: i like to wrap all my vars inside strings with the {} because its more official and it looks prettier in my text editor, but you dont need them...

Comment: I apologize I posted wrong variable for $album_id it is suppose to be $album['id'].

Comment: Anything you are the closest to figuring this out for me?

Comment: so then it would be =="album_id={$album["id"]}") {

Comment: To be honest with you though, I would do something like ?action=albumAction&album_id=### in your query string. Having the action command and action id in the same variable is counter productive... if you split it up you can have a whole block just for action "albumAction" where you could say if($_GET['album_id'] == $album["id"]) { ---- looks much simpler right?!

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate a little bit more on how to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14778/discussion-between-sublymerick-and-aaron-warnke)